# How to add each column of a data frame values in one by one new sheets using pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python pandas and have some doubt.I want to store each column of the data frame in each new sheet in excel.

Can anybody help me in implementing that.
I am putting code snippet as below for your reference.

```
df.columns

Index(['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp',
       'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked'],
      dtype='object')

for i in df.columns:
    print(df[i])
    with pd.ExcelWriter('output1.xlsx') as writer:  
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet'+i+')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're not slicing your dataframe at each point.

use :

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    for number,each_col in enumerate(df.columns,1):
        df[[each_col]].to_excel(writer,f'Sheet{number}',index=False)
```

or if you want the shetname to be the column name.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    for each_col in df.columns:
        df[[each_col]].to_excel(writer,f'Sheet{each_col}',index=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd

# created a dummy row in a new dataframe as per the column list you shared
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Dummy_PassengerId1', 'Dummy_Survived1', 'Dummy_Pclass1', 'Dummy_Name1', 'Dummy_Sex1', 'Dummy_Age1', 'Dummy_SibSp1',
       'Dummy_Parch1', 'Dummy_Ticket1', 'Dummy_Fare1', 'Dummy_Cabin1', 'Dummy_Embarked1']).T

# appended the appropriate headers to the dataframe
df2.columns = ['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp',
       'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked']
```

The above two steps were just to create a dummy dataframe with one row and required header. Its the line below that will meet your requirement (as I understood it): 'write each column of the dataframe to a new worksheet in the excel'. Hope this clarifies.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output1.xlsx') as writer:
    for col in df2.columns:      
        df2[col].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_'+col)
```